# Cancel a running scheduled query in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a **scheduled query** which runs every 30 mins. I had some issue and now there are multiple runs which are in progress simultaneously. I want to delete/stop those runs. Is there any way to do it without deleting the scheduled query itself? I know there is a way to stop BigQuery queries but not scheduled queries. The UI does not have any option of deleting any particular run.

Comment: Hi @Ankit Seth,Can you try this  `bq cancel <JOB_ID>` command or `CALLS BQ.JOB.CANCEL('<PROJECT_ID>.<JOB_ID>')`   [sql](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#cancel_a_job) ? Let me know whether it is helpful or not.

Comment: @kiranmathew I was unable to try. Someone else deleted that query.